# Why gflags doesn't start, it splashes and exits immediatly when I start it

Tags: debugging, windows-7, windbg, gflags

When I run gflags on windows 7, it should come up with UI but it doesn't. I see a brief black command window which then exits and gflags UI never comes up. It probably work from command prompt but I really want to work with it through UI.

Comment: Try running it from the command prompt. Perhaps there would be some error message.

Comment: I already did, there is no message and UI doesn't come up. The command prompt just returns.

Comment: Are you starting it using administrator privileges? Try also disabling UAC.

Comment: @Ari0nhh I did try that too, started it as administrator, same result.

Comment: start -> run -> type -> gflags _> hit enter gflags ui should pop up if not you have some other problems  (group policy , Exclusion , some lame av policies , malware , virus or worm modified the exe , may be a virus in the name of gflags.exe getting executed prior to original exe ,, whatever ,

Comment: @blabb it didn't start either. I have a 2nd PC where it does start normally but it doesn't even start it there with via start menu.

Comment: now as i commented it may be whatever xyz abc ijk reasons fire procmon filter gflags and watch  //// search the directories with dir /s gflags.exe  /// if there are more than one gflags dissect each one of them //// check if your path Environment variable points to the directory with gflags in it // /  this is not a question that is answerable by crystal ball gazing /// it should pop up an ui if it is properly installed and properly pathed else it is wild goose chase and it can become very wild if you try to chase in internet forums

Comment: Process Monitor is your friend. What did you find out?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably irrelevent  but since this post turned out in active list and i remembered that andy luhrs from windbg team answered a similar query and provided a temporary workaround i decided to post the liink and content here         from osronline lists

http://www.osronline.com/showThread.CFM?link=278979

aluhrs
xxxxxx@microsoft.com
Join Date: 16 Nov 2015
Posts To This List: 13
Gflags.exe is not able to run
Known issue that will be fixed in an upcoming release. You should be able to use 
the version of GFlags that is installed with any of the 8 or 8.1 kits, or copy 
the gflagsui.dll from those.